# How "=~" operator works inside the "IF" block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hi find the below two blocks:

***Block-I***

```
irb(main):001:0> s="acbbdd"
=> "acbbdd"
irb(main):002:0> /e/=~s
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> if /e/=~s then
irb(main):004:1* print "h"
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
```

***Block-II***

```
irb(main):001:0> s="acbbdd"
=> "acbbdd"
irb(main):006:0> if /c/=~s then
irb(main):007:1* print "h"
irb(main):008:1> end
h=> nil
irb(main):009:0>
```

Could you please help me to understand how `=~` works in `I` and `II` block? In the first block it doesn't match and returns `nil` but in the second block how `nil` is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `II` , /c/ matches s, so the `print "h"` get executed. You get an output (the string "h") and a return value from the print statement (nil)

Then the if block returns the return value of the last statement in the block, in this case nil.

run `print "h"` along will give you same result.

Answer (score 3):

In the first block, the string doesn't match `/e/` - there's no `e` in `"acbbdd"`.

In the second block, the string does match `/c/` - there is a `c` in `"acbbdd"`.

The reason the `nil` appears is because it is the return value of `print`, and hence of the entire `if` block.